# Scons Throwing Syntax Errors when Building gem5 Simulator on Manjaro (Arch) Linux

Tags: python, linux, scons, gem5

I need to setup a gem5 simulator for a computer architecture class. After downloading all the dependencies for Scons and running the build command for the ALPHA simulator, python throws a syntax error (shown below) flagging the use of a comma during the creation of a SystemExit exception.

To remedy this I tried running scons with python2 and python3. I even tried running my assignment in a virtual machine to no avail. Can someone familiar with Scons explain where this error is coming from and how to remedy it. It would be greatly appreciated.

Command Ran:

```
scons build/ALPHA/gem5.opt -j4
```

Error Message:

```
*** Error loading site_init file './site_scons/site_init.py':
  File "./site_scons/site_init.py", line 52

    except SystemExit, e:

                     ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

OS: Manjaro Linux x86_64

Kernel: 4.19.66-1-MANJARO

Python3 Version: Python 3.7.4

Python2 Version: Python 2.7.16

Latest Version of Scons

**Edit**

[Here's](https://www.mail-archive.com/gem5-dev@gem5.org/msg31011.html#) a link to an archived conversation about the problem. It comes frustratingly close to providing a solution, but it's all I've found on the issue thus far. The search continues.

Comment: Would be helpful if you include a URL to the gem5 project's website and/or repo

Comment: [Gem5 Project Repo](https://github.com/gem5/gem5)

Comment: Can you add output from scons -v ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are seeing looks like it should only happen with Python 3.5+ and SCons 3.0.0+

```
*** Error loading site_init file './site_scons/site_init.py':
  File "./site_scons/site_init.py", line 52

    except SystemExit, e:

                     ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

site_scons/site_init.py is a file in the package you downloaded to build and is using a form of python's except statement not allowed by python 3+.

Change it to:

```
except SystemExit as e:
```

See: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html for more info on python 3 and exceptions.

Note you should probably make a pull request or send a patch to the gem project once you resolve that and any other issues you run into.

Comment: Thanks for the response @bdbaddog. After fixing the syntax error a similar one is raised in the SConstruct script for gem5. It seems as though the script is written in python2 syntax but is being ran through the python3 interpreter. After speaking to some friends who followed the same steps on Ubuntu based machines and encountered no problems, this bug seems to only affect Arch Based Linux distributions. I'll continue researching the problem and add the solution here for posterity.

Comment: I'd guess Arch based linux distros shipping scons installed with py3.  You can create a virtualenv with py2.7 and then pip install scons there and give it a try?